# JDBC DatabaseMetaData#getTables() returns: ERROR 1463 (42000): Non-grouping field 'TABLE_TYPE' is used in HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mariadb

We get the following error message when asking via JDBC for the given tables in a MariaDB (via [DatabaseMetaData#getTables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))):

```
ERROR 1463 (42000): Non-grouping field 'TABLE_TYPE' is used in HAVING clause
```

We are using the MySQL Connector/J.

Any ideas what is the problem here?

Comment: The error message actually tells you exactly what the problem is (though it may not be clear to you, hence your post here).  The `TABLE_TYPE` column appears in the `HAVING` clause, but it did not also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  You can't do that.

Comment: Pittily you are wrong. This is legal sql. A `having clause` without a `group by clause` just means that the `group by clause` defaults to `group by ()`. As you can see in the answer this sql gets even generated by the JDBC driver.

Comment: Yes, but it still might be an error depending on the MySQL server mode.

Comment: No, it is not. Please read the question. It does not contain any SQL. The error occurs when you use jdbc getTables(). And it is not an error depending on the MariaDB sql_mode (not MySQL). In the actual versions of MariaDB this error is fixed. You can set the value `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in sql_mode and the below given statement will work despite this setting. Please see https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10663 ... this is simply a known bug in MariabDB which is fixed now.

Comment: The first problem is, that you call `getTables()` in Java using JDBC. And the error returned by the MariaDB database is in no way helpful, since you don't see the SQL-Statement behind this call that raises the problem and do ask yourself: Why can't I use `getTables()`. It took us a long time to find the real root cause. And I hope that this answer will help other JDBC users having the same problem.

Comment: Improved the subject of the question. I hope to make it clearer, that the problem is, the JDBC user does not see any SQL when calling `getTables()`. He just gets this funny error message as return value when he asks for Table Schema Data.

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises with MariaDB when using a version below 10.0.29 and the `sql_mode` contains the value `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. This is a known bug (see https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10663).

After enabling logging in the MariaDB we see the following statement:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_SCHEMA AS TABLE_CAT,
    NULL AS TABLE_SCHEM,
    TABLE_NAME,
    CASE
        WHEN TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' THEN
        CASE
            WHEN TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mysql'
            OR TABLE_SCHEMA = 'performance_schema' THEN 'SYSTEM TABLE'
            ELSE 'TABLE'
        END
        WHEN TABLE_TYPE = 'TEMPORARY' THEN 'LOCAL_TEMPORARY'
        ELSE TABLE_TYPE
    END AS TABLE_TYPE,
    TABLE_COMMENT AS RE MARKS,
    NULL AS TYPE_CAT,
    NULL AS TYPE_SCHEM,
    NULL AS TYPE_NAME,
    NULL AS SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME,
    NULL AS REF_GENERATION
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '<jdbc.catalog>'
    AND TABLE_NAME = '<jdbc.table>'
HAVING
    TABLE_TYPE IN ('TABLE',
    'VIEW',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL)
ORDER BY
    TABLE_TYPE,
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    TABLE_NAME
```

This statement is issued by the JDBC Driver when the method `getTables()` gets called (see github: [getTables() in the JDBC Driver](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/16a712ddb3f826a1933ab42b0039f7fb9eebc6ec/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.java#L760)).

This query for known tables then fails with given error message.

FIX 1: Remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from `sql_mode`

FIX 2: Upgrade to a MariaDB Version higher than or equal to 10.0.29